# WPF Button from Controltemplate isn't visible

Tags: wpf, button, controltemplate

I want to instantiate two Controls (an Expander and a Button) from two ControlTemplates. They are docked in a Dockpanel (right and left). The Expander is visible and it works fine, but the Button isn't visible.
The ControlTemplate of the Button in App.xaml:

```
...
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OpenFileButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Image Name="OpenFileButton" Source="F:\AudioNodeGUI_XAML\images\filebutton.jpg">

        </Image>
</ControlTemplate>
...
```

And the instantiation in a usercontrol:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="F:\AudioNodeGUI_XAML\images\FileInputNode.jpg"/>
    <DockPanel Name="dock" Width="151" Height="20" Margin="27,53,122,139">
        <Expander Name="expander" Template="{StaticResource FileExpander}" Height="20" Width="41" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="expand" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <ListView Name="usedFiles" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="140" Height="120" Opacity="0.5">
            </ListView>
        </Expander>
        <Button Name="OpenFileButton" Template="{StaticResource OpenFileButton}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

But the Button isn't visible, neither in the Designer (just the outline) nor in execution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add a size to the button

Comment: Please get familiar with WPF inspectors like WPF Snoop. They allow to inspect visual tree, play with properties values and fix a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue is just incorrect path to the image file. Unfortunately you won't have any tip about this kind of error neither in designer nor in output window. However if you have ReSharper it should highlight the path to the file if it doesn't exist

Comment: I solved the problem, as i removed the margin and rewrote it. I have no idea, where the problem actually was.